# How to check local stability of eigenvalues generated by a quintic characteristic polynomial?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-in-odes, characteristic-polynomial

Suppose we have a 5x5 matrix, how would we check the whether the eigenvalues are negative so that we can conclude they are locally stable?

As requested in the comment by Woody3:

here is the matrix:

```
m1 = {{-\[Beta]1 i2 - \[Beta]2 j - \[Beta]3 a - \[Mu], 
     0, -\[Beta]1 s, -\[Beta]2 s, -\[Beta]3 s}, {p \[Beta]1  i2 + 
      q \[Beta]2 j + r \[Beta]3 a, -b1, p \[Beta]1 s, 
     q \[Beta]2 s + \[Xi]1, 
     r \[Beta]3 s}, {(1 - p) \[Beta]1 i2 + (1 - q) \[Beta]2 j + (1 - 
         r) \[Beta]3 a, \[Epsilon], (1 - p) \[Beta]1 s - 
      b2, (1 - q) \[Beta]2 s + \[Xi]2, (1 - r) \[Beta]3 s}, {0, 0, 
     p1, -b3, 0}, {0, 0, 0, p2, -b4}} /. {s -> ss, i1 -> i1s, 
    i2 -> i2s, j -> js, a -> as};
```

where:

```
ss = FullSimplify[
   Together[
    Expand[(-b1 b2 b3 b4 + b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
      b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2)/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - 
      b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
      b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
      b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon])]]];
i1s = FullSimplify[
   Together[
    Expand[(-b2 b3^2 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Nu] - 
        b2 b3 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Nu] - b2 b3 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Nu] - 
        b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] \[Xi]1 + 
        b3 b4 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] \[Xi]1 - 
        b4 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Nu] \[Xi]1 + 
        b4 p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Nu] \[Xi]1 - 
        p1^2 p2 \[Beta]3 \[Nu] \[Xi]1 + 
        p1^2 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Nu] \[Xi]1 + 
        b3 b4 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] \[Xi]2 + 
        b4 p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Nu] \[Xi]2 + 
        p1^2 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Nu] \[Xi]2 + (
        b2 b3^2 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b2 b3 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b2 b3 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] \[Xi]1 (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        b3 b4 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] \[Xi]1 (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b4 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Mu] \[Xi]1 (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        b4 p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Mu] \[Xi]1 (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        p1^2 p2 \[Beta]3 \[Mu] \[Xi]1 (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        p1^2 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Mu] \[Xi]1 (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        b3 b4 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] \[Xi]2 (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        b4 p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Mu] \[Xi]2 (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        p1^2 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Mu] \[Xi]2 (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]))/(-b1 b2 b3^2 b4 \[Beta]1 - 
        b1 b2 b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 - b1 b2 b3 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
        b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
        b4 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
        p1^2 p2 \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
        b1 b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Xi]2 + b1 b4 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Xi]2 + 
        b1 p1^2 p2 \[Beta]3 \[Xi]2)]]];
i2s = FullSimplify[
   Together[
    Expand[(-b1 b3^2 b4 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] + b1 b3^2 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Nu] -
         b1 b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 \[Nu] + b1 b3 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Nu] - 
        b1 b3 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 \[Nu] + b1 b3 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Nu] - 
        b3^2 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] - 
        b3 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] - 
        b3 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] + (
        b1 b3^2 b4 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        b1 b3^2 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b1 b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        b1 b3 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b1 b3 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        b1 b3 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b3^2 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b3 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b3 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]))/(-b1 b2 b3^2 b4 \[Beta]1 - 
        b1 b2 b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 - b1 b2 b3 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
        b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
        b4 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
        p1^2 p2 \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
        b1 b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Xi]2 + b1 b4 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Xi]2 + 
        b1 p1^2 p2 \[Beta]3 \[Xi]2)]]];
js = FullSimplify[
   Together[
    Expand[(-b1 b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] + 
        b1 b3 b4 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] - b1 b4 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Nu] + 
        b1 b4 p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Nu] - b1 p1^2 p2 \[Beta]3 \[Nu] + 
        b1 p1^2 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Nu] - 
        b3 b4 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] - 
        b4 p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] - 
        p1^2 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] + (
        b1 b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        b1 b3 b4 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b1 b4 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        b1 b4 p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b1 p1^2 p2 \[Beta]3 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        b1 p1^2 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b3 b4 p p1 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b4 p1^2 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        p1^2 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]))/(-b1 b2 b3^2 b4 \[Beta]1 - 
        b1 b2 b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 - b1 b2 b3 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
        b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
        b4 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
        p1^2 p2 \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
        b1 b3 b4 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Xi]2 + b1 b4 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Xi]2 + 
        b1 p1^2 p2 \[Beta]3 \[Xi]2)]]];
as = FullSimplify[
   Together[
    Expand[(-b1 b3 b4 p1 p2 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] + 
        b1 b3 b4 p p1 p2 \[Beta]1 \[Nu] - 
        b1 b4 p1^2 p2 \[Beta]2 \[Nu] + 
        b1 b4 p1^2 p2 q \[Beta]2 \[Nu] - b1 p1^2 p2^2 \[Beta]3 \[Nu] +
         b1 p1^2 p2^2 r \[Beta]3 \[Nu] - 
        b3 b4 p p1 p2 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] - 
        b4 p1^2 p2 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] - 
        p1^2 p2^2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon] \[Nu] + (
        b1 b3 b4 p1 p2 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        b1 b3 b4 p p1 p2 \[Beta]1 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b1 b4 p1^2 p2 \[Beta]2 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        b1 b4 p1^2 p2 q \[Beta]2 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b1 p1^2 p2^2 \[Beta]3 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) - (
        b1 p1^2 p2^2 r \[Beta]3 \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b3 b4 p p1 p2 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        b4 p1^2 p2 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]) + (
        p1^2 p2^2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon] \[Mu] (-b1 b2 b3 b4 + 
           b4 p1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
           b1 b4 p1 \[Xi]2))/(-b1 b3 b4 \[Beta]1 + 
         b1 b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 - b1 b4 p1 \[Beta]2 + 
         b1 b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 - b1 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
         b1 p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 - b3 b4 p \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] - 
         b4 p1 q \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] - 
         p1 p2 r \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon]))/(-b1 b2 b3^2 b4^2 \[Beta]1 - 
        b1 b2 b3 b4^2 p1 \[Beta]2 - b1 b2 b3 b4 p1 p2 \[Beta]3 + 
        b3 b4^2 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
        b4^2 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
        b4 p1^2 p2 \[Beta]3 \[Epsilon] \[Xi]1 + 
        b1 b3 b4^2 p1 \[Beta]1 \[Xi]2 + b1 b4^2 p1^2 \[Beta]2 \[Xi]2 +
         b1 b4 p1^2 p2 \[Beta]3 \[Xi]2)]]];
```

and:

```
r0 = (\[Nu]/\[Mu]) (1/ss);
```

Comment: Do you have a matrix or a characteristic polynomial ??

Comment: @Woody3 I have added it in the question.

Comment: Er, my question was "matrix OR polynomial ?", because the title and the body speak differently.

Comment: @Woody3 The matrix will generate the CP